# Xinput doesn't produce any mouse events when cursor is over the Chrome/Opera

Tags: linux, google-chrome, mouseevent, opera, xinput

I am developing a Linux program on c++ for listening mouse/keyboard activities. I am using the `xinput` library: "`xinput test <device_id>`" command to listen to events. When mouse cursor is over the Chrome or Opera(no matter in focus it or not), the xinput doesn't produce any events, so my program is not working. Can it be that Chrome "eats" events and does not send it further?
The keyboard events are work fine thought.

I am trying to get some info of **root cause**(Why is this happen? What other software have the same effect?), but no results, so any help appriciated.

**Tried it on:**
Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04.01
Mate, Gnome3

Besides, I have tried with several mouse/touchpad devices, with the same impact and tried to listen all available devices(that are listed in `xinput list`) - no events produced even on Virtual devices.

**UPDATE:** I have tried the [libevdev](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libevdev/libevdev) library and it worked thought, but It doesn't appropriate to me, because it can't listen the Virtual devices(like `XTEST pointer` and `XTEST keyboard`) and uses a lot of cpu.